# Style is not applying to FF but on chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

This is really weird, whenever I open it on Firefox the style isn't applying. Everything looks fine in my css and even the link to it.

Here's the test page:

http://loreto.byethost13.com/testing/

Anyone has an idea about the problem?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your CSS. Check Firefox' console (Ctrl+Shift+J) for the line number and the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, just before your commented reset code, you have this:

```
a{text-decoration:none; color:#333;"}
```

Removing the quotation mark should fix the problem.

Comment: Good catch! I thought it was something else entirely! :D

Answer (score 2):

Line 51 of your stylesheet:

```
a{text-decoration:none; color:#333;"}
```

There is an unexpected double quote which is breaking the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you open up your stylesheet in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), you'll see that it's a big mess.

[image]

I think you may have some encoding issues here, make sure you have:

`@charset "utf-8";`

at the top of your CSS File.